# Awk command to Powershell equivalent

Tags: powershell, awk

I hope can you help me, essentially, I'm looking for the Powershell equivalent of the `awk` command:

```
awk '/"Box11"/ { print $0 }' test.txt|awk '{ SUM += $4} END { print SUM} '
```

What his does is print lines that contain the string Box11, then piping it to another awk that prints the total of the 4th column (delimited by spaces).

Comment: I don't know `awk` but I know powershell. Can you explain what your awk commands are doing?

Comment: Printing lines that contain the string Box11, then piping it to another awk that prints the total of the 4th column (delimited by spaces)

Comment: Please post an example of the text file and the output the command should produce.

Comment: I don't know Powershell but I know awk and in case it helps anyone else create a Powershell script, that chain of commands is wacky. You'd really do that job with just one command: `awk '/"Box11"/{sum += $4} END{print sum}' test.txt`.

Answer (score 26):

Multiple ways of doing it but this would do the trick:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt | Where-Object{$_ -match '"Box11"'} |
  ForEach-Object{($_ -split "\s+")[3]} | Measure-Object -Sum |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
```

Get a string array of the file. For each line that contains the string `"Box11"` we split the line on each group of spaces. Then pass the 4 element of each match to `Measure-Object`.

A short hand, if you value that, would look like this:

```
gc c:\temp\test.txt | ?{$_ -match '"Box11"'} | %{($_ -split "\s+")[3]} |
  Measure -Sum | Select -Exp Sum
```

If this file/string input had header this would be a good start as well. Assuming of course that your file is delimited with one space exactly.

```
Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " "
```

Comment: Thanks, how I can, convert this line in a file.bat or .file.exe?

Comment: `$_ -split "\s+"` is almost the same as `-split $_`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I needed to scrape a version number from a file where the version is the 3rd object (ex. `#define MODULE_FW  3`) and put it into a variable. `$version = Select-String -Path APPS\MyApp\IoDef.h -Pattern "#define MODULE_FW" | ForEach-Object{($_ -split "\s+")[2]}`

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is old, but I thought I'd add to this. Currently, if you have WSL (windows sub system for Linux) enabled, (windows 10 all version on systems that support virtualization, in the turn windows features on) with a distribution installed in the subsystem. You can can call Linux commands directly from windows

```
wsl -e awk '/"Box11"/{sum += $4} END{print sum}' test.txt
```

(borrowed from @Ed Moritn)
( or any awk command of your choice. )
Basically cmd or PowerShell takes the command and pipes it into the subsystem and the results are returned (bit of an over simplification, but in effect accurate). But the -e flag allows you to execute the command without opening an instance.

**edit**
Since writing this initial response, I have found two answers which are better solutions. The first is [GNUwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) This is a collection of Gnutils which have been ported to windows standalone .exe files including sed, awk, grep and many more, allowing you to call get-childitem | awk.exe '{print $1}' directly. These tools are fully portable with no installation required. The second option is Msys32, a platform that grew out of chocolatey (though it is almost fully code in dependant now) designed for cross compiling binaries. Once installed in the /bin folder, are many Linux utilities as exe files. most of these executable can be pulled from the bin and are portable with no required installation of dependencies. The reason msys32 is preferred (in my books) over the gnuwin32 is the fact that that gnuwin32 has gawk version 3.1 and msys32 has nawk and gawk vs 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get get `awk` for Windows now. I have been using it as a direct replacement and haven't had any problems yet.

It can be easily installed via [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/awk#individual)

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use Scoop to install command line tools like "awk".

For windows, you can use **[gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)** that can be installed with [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/awk#individual) like in [@MartinThé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4596403/martinth%C3%A9) aswer.

I prefer to use **[Scoop](https://scoop.sh/#/apps?q=gawk&id=955fdc2f074f489975103ccafb907527682c81a3)**.

Comment: Neither Gawk or Scoope are added as native PowerShell commands.

Comment: @Dennis. It's true!  Scoop would give you a package manager to install tools like gawk to extend PowerShell, but it's not native PowerShell commands. After installing gawk you can use the awk command in your environment with almost no friction. I use multiple good packages that improve the usability of my shell. Some other great tools that I install every new PC are base64, bat, btop, duf, fzf, gawk, jq, less, ripgrep, touch, yq...