# awk from bash to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I want to map the host port 5000 to the minikube port. The command already works in the bash but now I need it in PowerShell.

I have already changed the bash command to the point "Code in PowerShell" and now only need to replace the `awk` command.

Code in Bash:

```bash
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kube-registry-v0 | awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000
```

Code in PowerShell (`awk` to be replaced)

```bsh
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | Select-String -Pattern "kube-registry-v0" | awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it.  Select-string actually returns on object with multiple properties, and the `line` property has the string.

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system (kubectl get po -n kube-system |
  Select-String kube-registry-v0 | 
  foreach { -split $_.line | select -index 0} ) 5000:5000
```

Another way, using `where` or where-object, and the array index `[0]` notation:

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system (kubectl get po -n kube-system |
  where { $_ -match 'kube-registry-v0' } | 
  foreach { (-split $_)[0] ) 5000:5000
```

Similar post about awk and powershell:  [Awk command to Powershell equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110707/awk-command-to-powershell-equivalent)